# display URL Name same as whatever Travels Package selected by user

Tags: c#

I am developing a Travels website in asp.ne. for that I need to display URL Name same as whatever Travels Package selected by user.

What I have to do.
I have to design a separate Form for each Travels Package. or i can do another way.

Please give me your advise how to do this

Comment: Could you elaborate on your question? It is pretty unclear what is it that you are trying to do. Give some examples.

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a guess here. Are you after [Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx) and [RouteTables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routetable.aspx)?

You can have multiple routes point to the same aspx file and provide different parameters according to what is specified in the route.

Declare a route like this:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("","TravelPackage/{action}/{packageName}", "~/TravelPackagePage.aspx");
```

Then in your TravelPackagePage.aspx.cs:

```
string packageName = Page.RouteData.Values["packageName"]);
```

Your URL would look like this:

```
http://yourwebsite.org/TravelPackage/View/PackageX
```